# How to draw a dynamic line graph in Android ?

Tags: android

I've got a requirement for my application is to draw a line graph that can be changed on the fly. Eg. A heartbeat graph, a graph that represents the temperature etc..

How can I achieve this in a non-JS way on android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/1856369#1856369

Answer (score 5):

I would check out these open source Android graph libraries:

- http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/wiki/Screenshots
- http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home
- http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

Let us know which one worked for you.